# Theme(position.legend="none") doesn't work with coord_flip()

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, legend

I want to have a horizontal bar chart, but without legend. When I run the script below without coord_flip(), no legend shows. But when I run it with the coord_flip() argument, the legend appaers. I think this might be a bug. Does anyone know a different code with which I can skip the legend?

```
df <- aggregate(formula=mpg~cyl, data=mtcars, FUN=sum)            

fig <- ggplot(df, aes(x=cyl, y=mpg, fill=cyl, label=mpg)) +  
  geom_col() +
  coord_flip() +
  theme(legend.position="none") +
  theme_bw()
```

fig

Comment: I think it's simply because you're adding ```theme_bw()``` at the end, which puts the legend back. If you use ``` theme_bw() + theme(legend.position="none") ``` it will work.

Comment: I feel slightly embarrassed, you are right! Thank you :)